# Inserting in to a table from query results

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have one query which pulls data from a table and i need to then put the results in to another table in a different database, Here is my query for getting the data.

```
with
    BARCODEINNER(name, CODE, BARCODE_INNER) as
                (select
                    STOCKITEM.NAME,
                    STOCKITEM.CODE,
                    left(STOCKITEMPRICE.PRICE, 12) as EXPR1
                from [ PENNINE 2009 ] .DBO.PRICEBAND
                inner join [ PENNINE 2009 ] .DBO.STOCKITEMPRICE on PRICEBAND.PRICEBANDID = STOCKITEMPRICE.PRICEBANDID
                inner join [ PENNINE 2009 ] .DBO.STOCKITEM on STOCKITEMPRICE.ITEMID = STOCKITEM.ITEMID
                where (PRICEBAND.PRICEBANDID = '5045261')),
    BARCODEOUTER(CODE, BARCODE_OUTER) as
                (select
                    STOCKITEM_1.CODE,
                    left(STOCKITEMPRICE_1.PRICE, 12) as EXPR1
                from [ PENNINE 2009 ] .DBO.PRICEBAND as PRICEBAND_1
                inner join [ PENNINE 2009 ] .DBO.STOCKITEMPRICE as STOCKITEMPRICE_1 on PRICEBAND_1.PRICEBANDID = STOCKITEMPRICE_1.PRICEBANDID
                inner join [ PENNINE 2009 ] .DBO.STOCKITEM as STOCKITEM_1 on STOCKITEMPRICE_1.ITEMID = STOCKITEM_1.ITEMID
                where (PRICEBAND_1.PRICEBANDID = '5048507'))
select
    BARCODEINNER.CODE          as PRODUCTCODE,
    BARCODEINNER.NAME          as DESCRIPTION,
    BARCODEINNER.BARCODE_INNER as BARCODESINGLE,
    BARCODEOUTER.BARCODE_OUTER as BARCODEPACK
from BARCODEINNER as BARCODEINNER
inner join BARCODEOUTER as BARCODEOUTER on BARCODEINNER.CODE = BARCODEOUTER.CODE
order by BARCODEINNER.CODE
```

so i want to take the result set from this query and then put it in to this database

```
INSERT INTO [Label Software].dbo.[Label Information]
```

How can i achieve this?

Comment: You've looked at the online help for INSERT right?...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are both databases on the same server?

If so, you pretty much answered your own question there...

Have you tried this?

```
WITH BarCodeInner(Name, Code, Barcode_Inner) AS
(SELECT StockItem.Name,
      StockItem.Code,
      LEFT(StockItemPrice.Price, 12) AS Expr1
FROM [Pennine 2009].dbo.PriceBand
INNER JOIN [Pennine 2009].dbo.StockItemPrice ON PriceBand.PriceBandID = StockItemPrice.PriceBandID
INNER JOIN [Pennine 2009].dbo.StockItem ON StockItemPrice.ItemID = StockItem.ItemID
WHERE (PriceBand.PriceBandID = '5045261')),
  BarCodeOuter(Code, Barcode_Outer) AS
(SELECT StockItem_1.Code,
      LEFT(StockItemPrice_1.Price, 12) AS Expr1
FROM [Pennine 2009].dbo.PriceBand AS PriceBand_1
INNER JOIN [Pennine 2009].dbo.StockItemPrice AS StockItemPrice_1 ON PriceBand_1.PriceBandID = StockItemPrice_1.PriceBandID
INNER JOIN [Pennine 2009].dbo.StockItem AS StockItem_1 ON StockItemPrice_1.ItemID = StockItem_1.ItemID
WHERE (PriceBand_1.PriceBandID = '5048507'))
INSERT INTO [Label Software].dbo.[Label Information](Name, Code, Barcode_Inner)
SELECT BarCodeInner.Code AS ProductCode,
   BarCodeInner.Name AS Description,
   BarCodeInner.Barcode_Inner AS BarcodeSingle,
   BarCodeOuter.Barcode_Outer AS BarcodePack
FROM BarCodeInner AS BarCodeInner
INNER JOIN BarCodeOuter AS BarCodeOuter ON BarCodeInner.Code = BarCodeOuter.Code
```

Answer (score 0):

Just put the `INSERT INTO [Label Software].dbo.[Label Information]` Line before your query.

Answer (score 0):

you can try something like this:

```
    WITH BarCodeInner(Name, Code, Barcode_Inner) AS
(SELECT StockItem.Name,
      StockItem.Code,
      LEFT(StockItemPrice.Price, 12) AS Expr1
FROM [Pennine 2009].dbo.PriceBand
INNER JOIN [Pennine 2009].dbo.StockItemPrice ON PriceBand.PriceBandID = StockItemPrice.PriceBandID
INNER JOIN [Pennine 2009].dbo.StockItem ON StockItemPrice.ItemID = StockItem.ItemID
WHERE (PriceBand.PriceBandID = '5045261')),
  BarCodeOuter(Code, Barcode_Outer) AS
(SELECT StockItem_1.Code,
      LEFT(StockItemPrice_1.Price, 12) AS Expr1
FROM [Pennine 2009].dbo.PriceBand AS PriceBand_1
INNER JOIN [Pennine 2009].dbo.StockItemPrice AS StockItemPrice_1 ON PriceBand_1.PriceBandID = StockItemPrice_1.PriceBandID
INNER JOIN [Pennine 2009].dbo.StockItem AS StockItem_1 ON StockItemPrice_1.ItemID = StockItem_1.ItemID
WHERE (PriceBand_1.PriceBandID = '5048507'))
SELECT BarCodeInner.Code AS ProductCode,
   BarCodeInner.Name AS Description,
   BarCodeInner.Barcode_Inner AS BarcodeSingle,
   BarCodeOuter.Barcode_Outer AS BarcodePack

INTO [Label Software].dbo.[Label Information]

FROM BarCodeInner AS BarCodeInner
INNER JOIN BarCodeOuter AS BarCodeOuter ON BarCodeInner.Code = BarCodeOuter.Code
ORDER BY BarCodeInner.Code
```

as long as these two databases are on the same instance.
if not, try using linked server to do the same.